# Cron Jobs Explanation

Tags: php, cron

i would like some explanations.

i have a script

```
<?php
//mailing script here
?>
```

i have add the CRON job from my cpanel for every day.

1. i was getting : Permission denied (then i added "wget http://domain.com/performance_cron/daily.php > /dev/null" before the php tags and it is working). is that the best solution?
2. the jobs are being saved in my root directory "/" before public HTML. is this a good thing? or i how can i change the saving directory?
3. finally i am getting "2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected" though the job is being done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you dont have PHP installed as CGI then you need to use `wget path/to/php > /dev/null`
   if PHP installed as CGI try adding `#!/usr/local/bin/php` as a first line in php script,
   befor starting `<?php` tag. ("#!/usr/local/bin/php" = path to php executable)
2. it is good idea to protect cron scripts and put them outside public access
3. `"(" unexpected"` is a error in php code, try to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wget is a good way to call your webdir scripts.
2. If stored outside the webdir you can turn your php script into a stand alone php-cli script instead. Make the stand alone script executable using chmod or call a regular script through the php binary.
3. You would have to leave more info on that one. Follow the error hints.